# How do I assert that two arbitrary type objects are equivalent, without requiring them to be equal?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, equivalent

To accomplish this (but failing to do so) I'm reflecting over properties of an expected and actual object and making sure their values are equal. This works as expected as long as their properties are single objects, i.e. not lists, arrays, `IEnumerable`... If the property is a list of some sort, the test fails (on the `Assert.AreEqual(...)` inside the `for` loop).

```
public void WithCorrectModel<TModelType>(TModelType expected, string error = "") 
    where TModelType : class
{
    var actual = _result.ViewData.Model as TModelType;
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual, error);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(TModelType), error);
    foreach (var prop in typeof(TModelType).GetProperties())
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(prop.GetValue(expected, null), prop.GetValue(actual, null), error);
    }
}
```

If dealing with a list property, I would get the expected results if I instead used `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(...)` but that requires me to cast to `ICollection`, which in turn requries me to know the type listed, which I don't (want to).
It also requires me to know which properties are list types, which I don't know how to.

So, how should I assert that two objects of an arbitrary type are **equivalent**?

Note: I specifically *don't* want to require them to be *equal*, since one comes from my tested object and one is built in my test class to have something to compare with.

Comment: I haven't actually done any C# real development, but I really can't see how you can accomplish your task without recursion. Any object's field can be a complex object itself you want to test equivalence of.

Comment: @bp: You're right, of course. I'll probably refactor some of this to an internal method on the helper object that will call itself recursively, and that I'll call from this method. But I still need to figure out how to do different things with lists and or "regular" objects.

Comment: Aren't "regular objects" still objects the fields thereof are either more objects or primitive types?

Answer (score 1):

This works, not something I would really recommend but it works.

```
const string methodName = "Boolean SequenceEqual[TSource](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource])";

var sequenceEqual = 
        typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .First(m => m.ToString() == methodName);

foreach (var prop in typeof(TModelType).GetProperties())
{        
    var expectedValue = prop.GetValue(expected, null);
    var actualValue = prop.GetValue(actual, null);

    foreach (var item in a.GetType().GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (item.IsGenericType && item.Name.Contains("IEnumerable`1"))
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(
                (bool)sequenceEqual.MakeGenericMethod(
                    item.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                ).Invoke(null, new[] { expectedValue, actualValue })
            );              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the `.SequenceEqual()` method available. Do you know which assembly I need?

Comment: You need C# 3 with a reference to System.Core.dll and `using System.Linq`.

Comment: Hm... I'm in .NET 4 with a reference to System.Core.dll and `using System.Linq` - still no `.SequenceEqual()`...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will go down well, but one option would be to serialize the objects to a byte array and compare them. Of course this **assumes** that the objects you are dealing with are serializable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

namespace NGTests
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Person p1 = new Person() { FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Taylor", Children = { new Person() { FirstName = "Tamrin", LastName = "Taylor" } } };
      Person p2 = new Person() { FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Taylor", Children = { new Person() { FirstName = "Tamrin", LastName = "Taylor" } } };

      BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

      MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
      formatter.Serialize(ms1, p1);

      MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
      formatter.Serialize(ms2, p2);

      byte[] b1 = ms1.ToArray();
      byte[] b2 = ms2.ToArray();

      Console.WriteLine("Objects are Equal : {0}", b1.SequenceEqual(b2));

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  [Serializable]
  class Person
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Children { get; private set; }

    public Person()
    {
      Children = new List<Person>();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't assume that they'll be serializable, since I want to be able to do this with *any* type...